# using krutidev font to print css in html

Tags: html, css, printing, fonts

here is my css

```
@font-face {  
  font-family: kruti dev ;  
  src: url( '../../fonts/k010.ttf' ) format("truetype");  
}  

.hinditext {
    font-family: kruti dev;  
    font-size:18px;
}
```

and here is my html

```
<h3 class="hinditext">lkoZtfud izU;kl efUnj Jh egkdkys'oj </h3>
```

when  i display page in browser, then it show content in Hindi as below
[image: Browser display]

but when i give print commend ie print content in english like lkoZtfud izU;kl efUnj Jh egkdkys'oj.

Please can anyone tell me how i solve this issue and print content in hindi.

Comment: First, you should put quotes around font names that contain spaces. (And that's the official definition of "should", which is almost as strong as "must"!) Second, are you sure you're supposed to type ASCII characters there? I'd expect Unicode characters in the U+09xx range.

Comment: hey i am having issue in adding font-family krutidev as all my commas are converted into soem special characters.....any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

For Hindi font for web page and print, use this CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Kruti Dev';
src: url('../../Content/CustomCSS/Kruti Dev 010.ttf') format('truetype')}

.KrutiDev_hindi_text {
font-family: Kruti Dev !important;
font-size: 18px !important;}
```

Add `KrutiDev_hindi_text` class to the div you want to apply Hindi fonts to and add reference to this CSS in print function, i.e. `strid`=div id that you want to print.

Print function:

```
function CallPrint(strid) {

    var panel = document.getElementById(strid);
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'letf=100,top=100,width=600,height=600');

    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title> </title>');

    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write('<div class="container-fluid">');
    printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('<\/div>');
    //printWindow.document.write('<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
    printWindow.document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>');
    //printWindow.document.write('<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>');
    printWindow.document.write('<link href="/Content/BhardwajCustom.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
    printWindow.document.write('<style><\/style>');
    printWindow.document.write('</body>');
    printWindow.document.write('</html>');
    printWindow.document.close();

    //printWindow.print();
    setTimeout(function () {
        printWindow.print();
    }, 100);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting **kruti dev** word solved my problem.

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'kruti dev';
  /*****/
}
```

and where you use too.

Tested in Chrome, IE and FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

JUST USE  `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

IN HEAD SECION, your problem will solve.

Comment: The author of the question is not using Unicode but a font that displays A - Z as Hindi characters. So this is not going to help.

Comment: is it fixed or not??

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
@font-face{
font-family: kruti dev;
src: url("assets/text-font/K010.TTF") format("truetype");
}
.hindi{
font-family: kruti dev;
font-size: 25px;
}
    </style>
```

Make Sure you add ("") in css url("assets/text-font/K010.TTF");

Comment: url quotes can be single, double, or not present

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
$(document).ready(function() 
var lang = {};
lang["en"] = {
    hello_world : "Hello, World!",
};
lang["es"] = {
    hello_world : "घर जोडा!",
};
CurrentLang="es";
alert(lang[CurrentLang].hello_world);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add a paragraph or two summarizing how your code addresses the question. Thanks.